# Why does Google Play say "purchase successful" after installing free app?

Tags: google-play-store

I just installed [WiFi FTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.medhaapps.wififtpserver&hl=en&gl=US) app from my PC. I confirmed the installation from my PC and it required a password. After installation, it says "Purchase successful" - see the screenshot below. Why on earth does it say so? There was no "purchase", application should be free. What is all this about?

I don't understand what this question with these option is about... so I didn't submit this form, the application is already installed on the phone.

[image]

Comment: A first time download of a free app is considered a purchase without money involved because apps can change their price at any time. That allows you to redownload that app even if the developer decides to set a price on it. Because of this there can be offerings of often paid apps that are provided for free for a limited time. If you"purchase" it during that time you own the app no matter what price label is on it some days later.

Comment: @Robert I might be mistaken, but I thought a free app can never be changed to a paid app, but a paid app can temporarily be placed on sale.

Comment: Seems that you are right, a free app has to stay free according to https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?hl=en But an app can be set to non-public. In that case AFAIR only users who have purchased it previously can still download the app.